# laravel load another .env file and reload config values

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, environment

I want to load another `.env` file and also reload the config variables from env.
I have already loaded the `.env.landlord` file, but when I call the `config()` function, it still returns the value of the old env.

```
$dotenv = \Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable(base_path(), '.env.landlord');
$dotenv->load();

env('APP_NAME') // return 'landlord'
config('app.name') // return 'main'
```

How can I reload the env variables into config?

Comment: where are you trying to access on live server or via cron job?

Comment: where are you trying to `\Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable(base_path(), '.env.landlord');` ? it will not make a sense if you are loading the env file after the config population

Comment: This code in `AppServiceProvider.php` i use muulti tenanci, this reason i need change env file. in code run.